# Induction cooking: why ferromagnetic pan?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

In the image above, we have the principle of induction cooking. An alternating current is run through the coil, which causes a change in flux. This change in flux induces eddy currents in the conductive pan, and by Joule heating/resistive heating (P=VI), this causes the pan to heat  up.

So the only thing that you need is a pan that can conduct electricity/the eddy currents right? As long as the pan does not have a too low or a too high resistance.

However, why is the effect specifically optimal for ferromagnetic materials/conductors? How does the ability to magnetize somehow enhance the effect of induction heating? Does the magnetization of the pan itself somehow enhance the eddy currents or something?

Comment: This is something you can simply look up on your own. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_cooking#:~:text=For%20induction%20cooking%2C%20the%20base,metal%20bottom%20of%20the%20pan.

Comment: I don't get what they mean with 'the iron concentrates the current', what physical phenomenon causes the current to get 'concentrated'? by the magnetization and why?

Comment: @Stallmp - why is an iron core used in a transformer. (Well, not iron any more, but magnetic metallic glasses.)

Comment: It actually doesn't need to be ferromagnetic, it just need to have a high magnetic permeability. It just happens to be that ferromagnetic materials tend to have high magnetic permeability. Is there a reason for it ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ferromagnetic material is needed for the same reason that transformers working with low frequency alternating current (a.c.) need iron cores. The magnetic field generated by coils in the cooker's hob are supplemented by magnetic fields due to alignment by this field of magnetic domains in the iron. The resulting magnetic flux density may be hundreds of times larger than if there were no iron. Thus as the field changes, because it is a.c. that is passed through the coils, the changes are far greater than if there were no iron, and a much larger voltage is generated. Hence the heating effect is greater, despite the greater resistivity of the iron compared with that of (say) copper or aluminium.

Comment: Thanks! So basically the magnetization of the iron itself adds to the total flux, so you have an additional self inductance term? Is it correct to say that emf = -LdI/dt - MdI/dt?

Comment: Yes, you'll have a self-inductance term, since you can treat the saucepan base as the (loaded) secondary of a transformer.

Comment: +1 I was at first skeptical about this answer, but [the magnetic susceptibility of iron is indeed huge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility#Table_of_examples). Another point to check is whether the magnetization of iron can be reversed  so quickly.

Comment: @RogerVadim Just a gut feeling: in transformers you try not to use iron for high frequency because the hysteretic losses worsen the efficiency of the thing. Here you don't care if some power is "lost" because the magnetic domains can't readily follow the fields variations: you simply get more losses, i.e. more heat, which is what you are looking for anyway.

Comment: "Another point to check is whether the magnetization of iron can be reversed so quickly." I believe that induction hobs work at around 30 kHz. An internet source suggests that at this frequency the effective relative permeability of low carbon steel has roughly halved from the dc limit. If this is applicable it would not be problematic, but my 'facts' do need checking.

Comment: @Lorenzo Donati support Ukraine What you say about hysteresis losses makes sense, but the domains not readily following the field variation will also reduce the effective (real) relative permeability – which won't be beneficial. [I believe that you can take both these effects into account with a complex relative permeability.]

Comment: @PhilipWood Yep, but in general keep in mind that we are speaking about cookware, not top-notch material science for high-efficiency transformers. One of the biggest constraints is affordability. And high-quality cookware steel is much cheaper than any other material one could devise for that application, still being magnetic. So it's a tradeoff between cost, permeability, conductivity and suitability for food contact.

Comment: @PhilipWood After all one of the benefits of induction cooking is it's purported "energy-bill efficiency", if it were affordable only by high-wage people that can afford also high-tech cookware then why bother? Yes, cookware suitable for induction stoves *are* a bit more expensive, but not more expensive than good cookware and well below top-notch cookware used by "starred" chefs. They are a bit more expensive, but they last a lifetime.

Comment: When we got our first induction stove, we re-used all our existing pots and pans - they were not bottom-of-the-bin cheap, but nothing to write home about either. I mean, iron/steel is just the typical default material for cooking utensil, isn't it? I wasn't aware that price plays any role here at all.

Comment: @Lorenzo Donati I'm not sure how your last two comments connect with mine, but no worries, as they say.

Comment: @PhilipWood Well, it seemed like you thought there was a lot of material engineering optimization behind induction cookware, so I pointed out what I think is the "elephant in the room" here (consumer price). I doubt induction cookware designers gave too much thought to complex permeability characterization and the like. In that application I think there are bigger issues, e.g. thermal expansion, thermal conduction and food safety. But I admit I might be wrong. As I said in a previous comment, "a gut feeling". BTW, sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: @Lorenzo Donati  I think that your point about the sovereignty of price is a good one. I was just trying to understand the Physics. Best wishes.

Comment: @AnoE I think aluminium is also common, as you would expect. So the usual advice is either going to be worded as either "use iron/steel" or "avoid aluminium". Anything else is going to be really exotic. There's also glass/pyrex, which is used in ovens and not on cooktops (it wouldn't conduct heat well and might shatter from thermal stress)

Comment: @user253751 copper is sometimes used, but is relatively expensive and rare

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine You don't care about hysteresis "losses" because that's the whole point of it--all the energy is going to be burned up in either hysteresis or resistance and you don't care which.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Yep, that's what I said in my comment to PhilipWood. Wasn't I clear?

Comment: @Lorenzo Donati  And in your comment to Roger Vadim (fourth comment in the list). It was perfectly clear.